# IBM MQ: Access Violation Error when using CCDT (channel definition TAB) file

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

We are using the channel definition file to get the hostname and channel based on queue manager name.

But sometimes we are seeing the below error, is there any solution for this.

This is maybe due to multiple threads trying to access at the same time?

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructureHelper(IntPtr, System.Object, Boolean)

Details:

1. What kind of CCDT file is it? Binary or JSON?
   -Binary
2. Is your .NET application running in managed or non-managed mode?
   -Managed
3. What version of the MQ Client software are you using?
   -9.2.0.6
4. What release of MQ created the CCDT file?
   -8.x
5. How did you set the information for your program to use the CCDT file? - Set using command: setx MQCHLLIB C:\test\ /M
   setx MQCHLTAB cctdtest.TAB /M
6. Show us the C# code that creates the parameters and newing of the
   MQQueueManager class

```
var connectionProperties = new Hashtable(); 
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,  MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
//In case of network issues - reconnect to same queue manager
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MQHostName))  
{                          
  connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);                                
  connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, String.Format("{0}({1})", MQHostName, MQPort));
}
//Start Creating Inbound connection for reading the messages.
if (MQQueueNameIn != null && MQQueueNameIn.Length > 0)
{
  queueManagerIn = new MQQueueManager(MQManagerName, connectionProperties);                    
  queueIn = queueManagerIn.AccessQueue(MQQueueNameIn, MQC.MQOO_BROWSE + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);
}
```

Comment: @Roger: did you get a chance to look into the details?

Comment: @JoshMc: Can you please help?

Comment: Experts, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a lot more information. Update your question with the answers from the following questions:

- What kind of CCDT file is it? Binary or JSON?
- Is your .NET application running in managed or non-managed mode?
- What version of the MQ Client software are you using? Give all 4 digits. i.e. 9.3.0.2
- What release of MQ created the CCDT file?
- Show us the C# code that creates the parameters and newing of the MQQueueManager class.

Comment: I added the details in the question.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: How did you set the information for your program to use the CCDT file? Update your question with the information. Did you test the same CCDT with the MQ-supplied sample program like amqsputc or amqsgetc using the environment variables MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB? If so, did it work?

Comment: Updated the question. It works fine sometime and sometime it throws error.

Comment: What do you mean? What throws an error? The MQ samples or your own code? Please be more descriptive in your responses.

Comment: The sample works fine, but my code is throwing error as its running under a multithreaded environment. I have multiple adapters connecting to MQ through a windows service. On start of the service these adapters will try connecting to MQ parallelly.